# How to make changes in Airbnb Superset?

Tags: apache-superset

I deployed Superset on Ubuntu 14.04 from the source code and it works fine. Now I want to play with the superset code to make required changes. Like adding the Png downloadable option for charts.I made changes but it didn't reflect Superset build. How to make changes in Superset code that should reflect Superset on browser?
code Build Process:

1. git clone https://github.com/airbnb/superset
2. cd ${SUPERSET_HOME}/superset/assets
3. npm install             :   Will install the npm dependencies
4. pip install virtualenv  :   Will install virtualenv
5. virtualenv venv         :   Set virtualenv
6. . ./venv/bin/activate   :   activate virtualenv
7. pip install --upgrade setuptools pip : Will upgrade
8. npm run prod            :   Set NODE_ENV variable and run dependencies
9. cd ${SUPERSET_HOME}
10. python setup.py install

> //Create an admin user :
>   fabmanager create-admin --app superset
>
> //Initialize the database :
>   superset db upgrade
>
> //Load some data to play with : 
>   superset load_examples
>
> //Create default roles and permissions : 
>   superset init
>
> //To start the server : superset runserver -p 9002

Comment: the checkout and script suggested actually gives an error : sh: 1: node: not found

Comment: Did you manage to implement a button to download charts as a png, i'm looking to build the same thing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can read all the details here: https://github.com/airbnb/superset/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md#setting-up-a-python-development-environment

The main idea is to install for development using:

```
python setup.py develop
```

And run dev server:

```
superset runserver -d
```

Comment: Yes we started development mode by : 
python setup.py develop
superset runserver -d
and npm server with :
npm run dev 
And now it works fine. Thanks